# Stuck with Facebook fall back share dialog

Tags: java, android, facebook

When on Android there is not Facebook native app, then in order to share a post from another Android app a web dialog is being opened. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) on step 4 there is a description how to open that dialog (see `publishFeedDialog` function).

My problems is that all the other code described in this tutorial I have wrote in `AppActivity` which is a subclass of `Activity`. Hence, `getActivity()` method is not defined as far as it is defined for `Fragment`s. To solve this problem I have defined a private variable like this:

```
    private Activity activity;
```

Assigned a value in `onCreate` method:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = this;

     // .......
 }
```

and used in all places where there was a call of `getActivity()`.  As I not a Java neither an Android expert, I would like to understand whether I have done it correctly.

Comment: instead of doing methodCall(activity), couldn't you just do methodCall(this) ? Seems to me like you don't actually need that variable...

Comment: fackbook? Edit title

Comment: `this` cannot work, as here `Toast.makeText(getActivity()` `this` is of type `OnCompleteListener`.

Comment: @Aevy Yes Facebook! I integrate Facebook into my iOS app.

Comment: @Narek I'm just pointing out a typo in title.

Comment: @Arvy oh fack, that was a really type like this one :D